# If two tours are starting at the same time, one lasts for 15 minutes and the other for 20, when do they meet again?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are two tours that are starting at the same time. One is 15 minutes and the other is 20 minute. What time will both tours meet back? How can I express this in an equation? Thank you.

#### Context

They both start at the same time but one runs for 15 minutes and the other runs for 20. They will meet back up with each other in an hour I believe because the 15 minute one is running 5 minutes faster than the 20 minute tour.

Comment: The question seems to be missing information.  What do you mean by "meet back"?

Comment: you can express it using the lowest common multiple as a way forward. No need for an equation here.

Comment: They both start at the same time but one runs for 15 minutes and the other runs for 20. They will meet back up with each other in an hour I believe because the 15 minute one is running 5 minutes faster than the 20 minute tour.

Comment: I changed the tags. I think the one I chosen fits better, though please update if needs be.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\text{tour A} = 15\,\,\text{minutes} = 3\times 5 \,\,\text{minutes}\\
\text{tour B} = 20\,\,\text{minutes} = 4\times 5 \,\,\text{minutes}\\
$$
thus the lowest common multiple will occur by
$$
4\times\,\,\text{time for tour A} = 4\times 3\times 5 \,\,\text{minutes}\\
3\times\,\,\text{time for tour B} = 3\times 4\times 5 \,\,\text{minutes}
$$
both equate to $60$ minutes as you already found.

Answer (score 0):

Without algebra, you can simply list out the times that the tours run:

$$\text{tour A}: 15, 30, 45, \color{red}{60}$$
$$\text{tour B}: 20, 40, \color{red}{60}$$

Therefore tour $A$ and tour $B$ start at $60$ minutes.

Alternatively using your intuition, the difference between tour $A$ and tour $B$ will increase by $5$ minutes every tour. We want this difference to be a multiple of $20$. Since $5 \times 4  = 20$, this will happen in $4$ tours of tour $A$, or at $4 \times 15 = 60$ minutes.